# Indefinite article a/an

Tags: php, strings

I'm looking for feedback to improve this function. The purpose is to pass a noun and append the appropriate indefinite article ("a" or "an").

A known issue with this code is that it doesn't address words with a vowel sound but a consonant first letter, such as "honor" or "hour". I cannot include 'h' in the list of vowels, though; words like "home" or "horror" have a harder 'h' sound and use the article "a".

```
function aan ($string) {
    return (
        in_array(
            strtolower(substr($string, 0, 1)),
            array('a','e','i','o','u')
        ) ? 'an' : 'a'
    ).' '.$string;
}
```

Current output:

```
print 'Become '.aan('All-access').' member'; // Become an All-access member
print 'Become '.aan('Basic').' member'; // Become a Basic member
print 'It has been '.aan('interesting').' experience'; // It has been an interesting experience
```

Comment: The logic is flawed. In English, you can't base a/an on written form. You have to base it on word pronuncation.  If you don't have the pronunciation for every word, you  will never make it work. Common examples - "a unit" vs "an uncle"

Comment: @Sulthan ... as I mention in the second paragraph.

Comment: it is unclear what kind of feedback you are looking for to improve this function. performance, readability, speed, efficiency....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to use `stristr()` and `$string[0]`.

```
function indefinite_article_heuristic($string) {
    return (stristr('aeiou', $string[0]) ? 'an ' : 'a ') . $string;
}
```

`stripos()` would probably be slightly more efficient, but you would have to do

```
function indefinite_article_heuristic($string) {
    return (FALSE === stripos('aeiou', $string[0]) ? 'a ' : 'an ') . $string;
}
```

which looks icky.

Answer (score 2):

A tiny improvement to reduce a string concatenation:

```
function aan ($string) {
    return (
        in_array(
            strtolower(substr($string, 0, 1)),
            array('a','e','i','o','u')
        ) ? 'an ' : 'a '
    ).$string;
}
```

In order to help get your logic for more cases (ie, your Honor or Hour examples), you may wish to visit the [English StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) to get help in figuring that logic out. Then you can code that as well.